# Disable the Keyboard Shortcuts overlay

Tags: 14.04, unity

I am automatically provisioning many fresh Ubuntu 14.04 installs and would like to know how to disable the Keyboard Shortcuts overlay from the command line?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have dconf installed then to disable:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/shortcut-overlay false
```

and to switch back on

```
 dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/shortcut-overlay true
```

If you don't have dconf installed then install it through

```
sudo apt-get install dconf
```

Comment: I am provisioning over ssh and can't use X11 which `dconf` seems to require `error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`

Answer (score 1):

This is used in `/usr/sbin/guest-account`:

```
mkdir -p "$HOME"/.cache/unity
touch "$HOME"/.cache/unity/first_run.stamp
```